# Excel file loading in SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012, msbi, foreach-loop-container

I want to move the failed excel files to error folder and loaded excel files to archive folder in **SSIS** The excel file having multiple sheets and the folder contains multiple excel files.

Comment: I think there's an option to write a VB script for that in SSIS package

Comment: can you share me any suggested links

Answer (score 0):

You can use a File System Task for this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/file-system-task

You would place this in your loop, and I'd set a success/failure (Boolean) variable to control the destination directory.